# {'sales@mydomain.co': (553, b'5.7.1 <abc@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user sales@mydomain.co')}

Tags: python, django, email, django-forms

I have a contact form on my website where users fill in their name, email and message to contact support which in this case is `sales@mydomain.co` and say the sender's email is `abc@gmail.com`. When a user submits the form, the form yields an error `{'sales@mydomain.co': (553, b'5.7.1 <abc@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user sales@mydomain.co')}`

The form works if the sender's email belongs to the organization `sales@mydomain.co`. Is it possible to for a user to send an email(using a different organization email, such as Gmail) through the online form?

here is my forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your email', max_length=100) 
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=600, widget=forms.Textarea)
    
    def send_mail(self):
        logger.info("Sending email to customer service")
        subject = "Site message"
        message = f"From: {self.cleaned_data['name']} <{self.cleaned_data['email']}>\n{self.cleaned_data['message']}"
        sender_email = self.cleaned_data['email']  # Use the user's email as the sender
        recipient_list = ['sales@mydomain.co']  # My domain email address
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            sender_email,
            recipient_list,
            fail_silently=False,
    )
```

Comment: You can not use it as `sender_email`, otherwise you are sending an email in the name of someone else, some email servers guard against that.

Comment: An idea might be to include it as a `reply-to`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, you can not send an email on behalf of someone else with the gmail email backend. Indeed, the [documentation regarding *Send emails from a different address or alias*](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) says:

> **If you own another email address**, you can send mail as that address.

But even if some email service allows that, if the domain is different it will be quite easy to see that this is email is *spoofing*: that the from address does not belong to the server that initiated the communication.

You typically add a *reply to* address, to make it convenient to reply to the person that has filled in the form, with:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

subject = 'Site message'
message = f"From: {self.cleaned_data['name']} <{self.cleaned_data['email']}>\n{self.cleaned_data['message']}"
sender_email = self.cleaned_data['email']
recipient_list = ['sales@mydomain.co']
email = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=recipient_list, reply_to=[sender_email])
email.send()
```

you could also add the `sender_email` in CC/BCC.